# Is there a way to display a PowerApp(using SharePoint list) on a SharePoint page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

So having previously being experienced using InfoPath & SharePoint Designer for form and workflows, I thought it would be time to try using PowerApps to make forms from SharePoint lists however the first stumbling block I've come across is being able to display this app on a SharePoint page - is it even possible?

With InfoPath, there was a web part specifically for it or you open the form in a modal window but I've not been able to find any info online about being able to do something similar with PowerApps.

Has anyone tried this yet? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet! But it is in the planning of future improvements. Check out this great ignite session: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Ignite-Content/BRK3326-Dive-into-PowerApps-building-apps-that-mean-business/m-p/10335/highlight/true#M350

Slide 51 for the roadmap

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. Below is the lines that i got from the site. Reference below

> Apps that you create in this way will show up as views that can be shared and launched from within the new SharePoint modern list experience.  This will allow you to leverage PowerApps to build custom, mobile-optimized views of your existing lists and share them with your co-workers.  Furthermore, since PowerApps is a cross-platform service, you are able to run the apps you create across all of your devices including Windows, iOS, Android, and the web browser.

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powerapps-and-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile it is possible to embed a PowerApp in an IFrame into a Sharepoint page. To display the PowerApp doesn´t work reliable with IE and it is recommended to use Chrome instead.
Have a look at this:
[Link to PowerApps Forum](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Forum/PowerApps-embedded-in-SharePoint-bugs-in-IE-and-Edge/m-p/42727/highlight/true#M17709)

Answer (score 0):

use this link for powerapp in SharePoint page:
https://wonderlaura.com/2017/04/27/embed-powerapps-on-sharepoint-modern-pages/

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)